# Sniffing TCP and UDP network traffic

Tags: udp, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I am trying to examine UDP and TCP traffic between two (or more) devices on the same local network. I am trying to see the data that the devices are passing to each other. In an example I have set up, I am passing a plain text string from one device to the other.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

I have tried using Wireshark to capture wireless traffic as shown [here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN) with my network adapter in monitor mode, but have not been able to see the plain text data being passed around.

Thanks :)

Comment: "have not been able to see the information I want"? Please be more informative

Comment: We don't know why you didn't see the information you needed either.In fact we don't know what kind of information you did or didn't see, nor what you want to see.

Comment: Those are good points :) I updated the question above. The data being passed around should be ascii or utf-8 encoded, but I could be wrong. Still, I have been passing around some sample UDP packets, and have not been able to see those showing up in Wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the layout of your network, I am guessing that the devices you are trying to capture the data between are not communicating via the wireless network (maybe they are connected via ethernet cable instead?) . Alternatively, you may need to capture in promiscuous mode (which might only be available on linux, but I cant remember).

In the general case, the network traffic needs to be hitting the network adapter you are capturing on. The simplest way to ensure this is to capture on one of the actual devices.